# I find it easier to get a visa for Portugal, as I have relatives there. But my aim is to spend more time in Italy

Tags: schengen-visas

I find it easier to get a visa for Portugal, as I have relatives there. But my aim is to 2-3 weeks in Italy, and just a few days to visit my Portugal relatives.
If I book my flights  with a 2-3 week gap, will it be a problem to enter Italy?

Comment: @JonathanReez: The answer can be found within the large amount of text submitted as answers to that previous question, but the _questions_ are clearly distinct. Not a duplicate.